# add new column periodically on data source using powerapps or powerautomate

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, periodic-task

Is it possible to modify a data source to create periodically (e.g., every day) a new column on power apps or power automate?

I have to create an attendance app where every day we must collect data, creating one column.

For example,

First day:

```
name, 10/10
john, true
louise, false
mark, true
```

Second day:

```
name, 10/10, 11/10
john, true, false
louise, false, false
mark, true, true
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by creating a scheduled cloud flow. In your Power Apps solution (modern designer) click `New` and in the flyout navigate to `Automation` => `Cloud flow` => `Scheduled`.

Comment: beside scheduling, can I append columns on an existing data source?

Comment: No, that's not the way to log this kind of data. Remember you can only create a limited number of columns per table. What you may need is creating a record for every day/person combination. For Dataverse there is an **Add a new row** action avaible.